# Evaluate function call within function call

Tags: r

When I use this with atomic vector, it works:

```
x = data.frame(myvar = 1:10)

test_atom = function(var, maxvalue = max(var)) { 
    return(maxvalue)
}

test_atom(x$myvar)
# [1] 10
```

But when I try to evaluate a column in a data frame, there is a problem:

```
test_df = function(data, var, maxvalue = max(var)) { 
    params = as.list(match.call()[-1])
    data$var = eval(params$var, data)
    return(maxvalue)
}

test_df(x, myvar)
# Error in test_df(x, myvar) : object 'myvar' not found
```

Note however that the following works ok, so evaluation seems fine:

```
test_df2 = function(data, var, maxvalue = max(var)) { 
    params = as.list(match.call()[-1])
    data$var = eval(params$var, data)
    return(data$var)
}

test_df2(x, myvar)
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

How to properly evaluate the argument so that it detects the maximum value of x$myvar?

**EDIT** To properly spell out my intention, I want the possibility to set the value for `maxvalue` manually, but in case I leave it blank, it should set itself to the maximum value of `myvar`. This could be achieved by a conditional statement within the function to check whether the argument is `NULL` and then setting the `maxvalue` to maximum value of `myvar` within the function - but I wanted to do it in a simpler way, i.e. not within the function.

*Example - both should be possible:*

```
test_df(x, myvar, 5) # I set the value of the last argument manually
test_df(x, myvar) # I leave it blank - and it sets itself to the max value of `myvar`
```

Comment: Try `test_df(x, x$myvar)`. This return '10'.

Comment: @symbolrush of course. But I want this function to accept data frame as its first argument and then individual variables without using the `$` function. Such format is customary in many R functions, such as `subset(x, myvar > 5)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a variable with `$` subseting, you have to tackle it a little differently.

```
test_df3 = function(data, var, maxvalue = max(data[,var])) { 
  return(maxvalue)
}
```

You should pass `data` (which is your data frame) and subset it by the `var` value to max, or it won't be able to guess what you're trying to get the max of.

In case `var` is a column name, it has to be a string or R will try (at the call time) to find a variable/object with this name to give its value to the function.

This gives:

```
> test_df3(x,'myvar')
[1] 10
> test_df3(x,'myvar',5)
[1] 5
```

Comment: Interesting. Actually, my intention (which I will add to my question) was that this would allow the user to either set the value manually, or, if she leaves the argument blank, it would set itself to max value of `myvar`. I know I could write some conditional statement within the function to check whether the argument is `NULL` and if yes, set it to max value of `myvar`, but I thought there would be a simpler way.

Comment: @jakub I'll wait your update on the question, add some examples calls with expected output so it's clear what you wish to achieve.

Comment: well, I could do `test_df5 = function(data, var, maxvalue = max(data[, deparse(substitute(var))])) {return(maxvalue)}` which would allow me to use unquoted variable name. But it looks ugly... isn't there a better way?

Comment: @jakub I don't think, and the deparse trick prevent you of using a numeric index like `test_df3(x,1)` for example.